# Firebase Realtime Database search returns the parent

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have created data like this,

```
device
    [random ID]
         id: "435345"
         token: "homer"
    [random ID]
         id: "594935"
         token: "marge"
```

I used the following code to find "id" by "token".

```
const db = admin.database().ref("device");
db.orderByChild("token").equalTo(token).once("value",
    function(data){
        console.log("key= " + data.key + " ,value= " + data.val());
     }
)
```

If `token` is "marge", I would expect `data.val()` would be "594935". But when I ran the code, the result was like this,

```
info: key= device ,value= [object Object]
```

I think the `data` is not the second child of "device", but the "device" node itself. What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a loop to access children values of a list

> Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you need to loop over the result

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

Therefore, your code should look something like this:

```
const db = admin.database().ref("device");
db.orderByChild("token").equalTo(token).once("value", function(data_snapshot) {

data_snapshot.forEach(function(data_child) {

console.log(data_child.val());

});

});
```

Comment: Type[Java]Script documentation is always bad, I perceive. The IDE did not show any description for `forEach` and the only way I could do was pressing F12 to see the signature. The argument seemed to be a lambda that returns a boolean. So I added `return false;`. Also, the `data_child` is still the container, so I used `data_child.val().id`. Also, I only need one (and there should be) "id" for a token, so I added `limitToFirst(1)` between `equalTo` and `once`. I am not sure if that is the best way, but guessing by the name, I think it would do the thing I expect to do.